# Are there any online Persian/Farsi dictionaries that include diacritics for pronunciation?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, persian

Persian is written in the [Perso-Arabic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Overview_table) and, like Arabic and Hebrew, is written without vowels. This makes it hard for a learner to decipher the exact pronunciation of any Persian word without referring to an audio source or a dictionary that includes [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Diacritics).

Are there any online Persian dictionaries (either paid or free) that include diacritics (especially conjugated verbs)?

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find any with diacritics, but these dictionaries all indicate pronunciation of each word by romanization:

- [Hayyim](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/hayyim/) (Persian-English)
- [Steingass](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/steingass/) (Persian-English; also via [Alpheios](https://alpheios.net/))
- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Persian_language) (Persian-English)
- [Vajehyab](http://www.vajehyab.com/) (Persian)

Wiktionary is the only one with pronunciation of conjugated verbs.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to ba's answer, [vajehyab.com](http://vajehyab.com) and [dictionary.abadis.ir](http://dictionary.abadis.ir), which are not dictionaries by themselves, but provide you access to `دهخدا`, `معین` and `عمید`  which are major contemporary Persian-Persian dictionaries. and `دهخدا` and `معین` do in fact show the diacritics, though not in a usual way.

[image]

[image]

i.e. they only shows the letters that do have a diacritic (in this case, letters `د` and `م`, and their diacritics. which in this case means the whole word is: `دُشمَن`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether after 2 years and 5 months it's still in any avail to give an answer or not but:

> https://www.persianlearner.com/pages/English-Persian-dictionary.php

This dictionary does have audio pronunciation and (persian) phonetic pronunciation with decent examples modified in both Standard and Colloquial Farsi/Persian.

And this website:

> https://forvo.com/

This is not a dictionary but a dictionary of pronunciation, you can search your persian/Farsi word and hear its pronunciation.

Comment: +1 for Forvo, an amazing compilation of audio recordings of words in many languages. In my experience, if I don't find a word on Forvo, it's probably because I spelled it wrong. Occasionally you'll get an unclear or confusing recording, but in that case you can request another.